# Cost effective way to start java card development

Tags: javacard

What’s the most cost effective way to start Java card development?

I’ve spoken to several individuals and they have recommended purchasing the following SDK: https://www.taisys.com/p-detail?id=df8bIvFE5tKyOuGwfx4-MUHPKc8kbAnlcMBg-sR-6Q. However it seems quite expensive for a hobbyist like myself. Therefore I just wanted to ask where would be the best place to:

- Purchase the hardware required to set up a testing environment. This would include a 1) card reader 2) blank SIM cards, ideally NFC enabled 3) a suitable set of feature phones to test applications
- How would I go about setting up the software development environment on my desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/martinpaljak contains bits and pieces for everything from applet building to loading to testing as FOSS.

Comment: Thanks does it include information on where to purchase card readers and blank SIM cards